# form-data library throwing cannot read property of null error when trying append attachments to send via request.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, form-data

When I try to make a `request.post` with `form-data` for attachments I am getting the following error. The error is coming from the form-data library.

```
var filename = options.filename || value.name || value.path;
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

This is what my form construction and appending looks like. I am basically attaching a JSON Web Token and an image file.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('jwt', jwt);

var imgToAttach = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'abc.jpg'));
formData.append('attachmentA', imgToAttach);

sendRequest(formData);
```

The sendRequest function looks like this.

```
    function sendRequest(formData) {
      var reqOptions = {
        url: options.host, 
        formData: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      };
      request.post(reqOptions, function (err, resp) {...}
```

I've been trying to resolve this issue for a while but nothing has worked. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you manually setting the `Content-Type`? Not only that, it's the wrong content type (application/x-ww-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data are completely different formats -- the former not supporting binary data for example).

Comment: Also, where is `jwt` set? Is it an object that you meant to convert to to a JSON string first?

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, request module can't get the name from form-data

Try this instead:

```
const formData = {
    attachmentA: {
      value: imgToAttach,
      options: {
        filename: "abc",
        contentType: "jpg"
      }
    }
};
```