# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, form-data, request-promise

I am learning and experimenting on `NodeJs`. I am using `request-promise` to call another api from `NodeJs`. I am using `form-data` to create a form and send it to another api.
My snippet:

```
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const FormData = require('form-data');
....

var sendToAPI = async (fileObjBuffer, myId, timestamp) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileData', fileObjBuffer);
    formData.append('myId', myId);
    formData.append('fileName', timestamp);

    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: '<URL>',
        formData: formData,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'
        },
        json: true
    };
    try {
        let apiResult = await requestPromise(options).promise();
        console.log('\n\napiResult: ', apiResult);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in sending to api: ',error);
    } 
}

var fetchAllData = async () => {
    let query = 'select * from demo_db.demo_table;';
    let fileObject = "";
    var result;
    try {
        //cassandra query
        result = await client.execute(query, [], { prepare: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in fetching data from Cassandra: ',error);
    }
    result.rows.forEach(resultObj => {
        fileObject = fileObject +resultObj['room_id'] +":"+resultObj['message_id']+":"+resultObj['original_message'] +":"+resultObj['send_date'] +":"+  resultObj['sender'] +"%";
    });
    let fileObjBuffer = new Buffer(fileObject);
    let myId = uuidv4();
    let timestamp = date.format(new Date(), 'YYYYMMMDDhhmmss', false);  
    sendToAPI(fileObjBuffer,myId,timestamp);
}
```

My error:

```
error in sending to api:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
at FormData._getContentDisposition (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:226:40)
at FormData._multiPartHeader (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:177:33)
at FormData.append (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:70:21)
at appendFormValue (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/request.js:326:21)
at Request.init (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/request.js:337:11)
at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:45:29)
at new Request (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
at request (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
at sendToAPI (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/schedulerTest.js:52:25)
at fetchAllData (/home/bhushan/NodeJS-Scheduler/schedulerTest.js:95:2)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The code what you have pasted doesn't contain the error part. The error states that `name of null` means you are trying to access name of `null` which may be an object or array, so paste your full code otherwise its difficult

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597174/form-data-library-throwing-cannot-read-property-of-null-error-when-trying-append

Comment: @Subburaj, I have just written another simple function `fetchAllData` to create `fileName`, `myId`, and `fileObjBuffer` values and then called `sendToAPI()` from `fetchAllData`.

Comment: Hi, @VictorF, I have seen the post but I didn't understand, how to implement it in my case.

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: @VictorF, actually, there is another function `fetchAllData` which creates `fileName`, `myId`, `fileObjBuffer` values. From `fetchAllData`, I am calling `sendToAPI()`. I checked `fetchAllData` function but there nothing like `name`.

Comment: Hm. Sound weird. Could you try posting that function, please?

Comment: @VictorF I have edited the question have a look.

Comment: search in your project where you have used the name property. Then post that part of code so it will be easy for community to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request-promise` internally handles `form-data`. Therefore no need to use `form-data` explicitly. Instead I made normal object in following way:

```
var formData = {
    fileData: {
        value: fileObjBuffer,
        filename: timestamp
    },
    fileName: timestamp,
    myId: myId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises because in the formData key of requestPromise method you do not need to actually pass formData but an object.

request-promise internally creates formData from the object passed.

```
let formData = {
  fileData: fileObjBuffer,
  fileName: timestamp,
  myId: myId
}

let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: '<URL>',
    formData: formData, // formData here is an object
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'
    },
    json: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any good solution. So, I have added a function which will test if the value is empty or not. if it is empty then don't add it into the formData object else add it.

```javascript
const FormData = z.require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();

const addFormData = (key, value) => {
    
  // If value is an array
  if(Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0) {
    form.append(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    return;
  }
  
  // If value is string or number
  if(value) {
    form.append(key, value);
  }
  
  // TODO: You can add aditional checks if you would like to verify if it is non-empty object etc
  
} 

addFormData('name', 'Rahul')
addFormData('age', 28)
```